# Checking GPIO State in Embedded C Programming

Tags: c, embedded, gpio

We have an embedded C programming assignment where we have to implement a state machine that changes a series of LED's depending on a Joystick Input. Two of the conditions are: "if Left LED is on and Down is Pressed Change to Right LED" and "if Right LED is on and Down is Pressed Change to Left LED". I know how to turn on certain LED's on button presses but I have no idea how to check the state of a GPIO pin/LED and change another LED based on the state when the joystick is used. I basically just want to know how to "call" the state of an LED.

This is the state machine sample code so far:

```
void
StateMachine ()
{
  // REPLACE THE FOLLOW CODE WITH YOUR SOLUTION
  // This code just toggles top LED and set left or right LED.
  //
  // Solution.

  uint8_t Joystick;
  uint8_t Toggle = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    Joystick = GetJoystick();

    if (Joystick == 'L')
    {
      WriteLED ('L', LED_ON);
      WriteLED ('R', LED_OFF);
    }
    else if (Joystick == 'R')
    {
      WriteLED ('L', LED_OFF);
      WriteLED ('R', LED_ON);
    }

    if (Toggle == 0)
    {
      WriteLED ('T', LED_ON);
      Toggle = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      WriteLED ('T', LED_OFF);
      Toggle = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Update: This is my `WriteLED` method

```
void
WriteLED (uint8_t LED, uint8_t State)
{
  // Check for correct state
  if ((State != LED_OFF) && (State != LED_ON))
  {
    return;
  }

  // Turn on/off the LED
  switch (LED)
    {
    case 'L':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD4_GPIO_Port, LD4_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'T':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'B':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD6_GPIO_Port, LD6_Pin, State);
      break;
    case 'R':
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin (LD5_GPIO_Port, LD5_Pin, State);
      break;
    }

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the assignment is specifically asking for a "state machine" then the software should somehow have different internal "states" corresponding to the different LED output requirements. There are lots of ways to represent a state machine -- (were you shown one?) -- For example:

```
// enumeration of the required states
enum OutputState {
    stateAllOff, // I'm *guessing* this is the required initial state?
    stateLeftLED,
    stateRightLED,
    // ... any other states that are specified.
    // ... but *not* random combinations of LEDs that are not part of the specification.
};

enum OutputState currentState = stateAllOff; // or whatever initial state is required

// [...] I'm not going to do the actual assignment here
```

A state machine doesn't have to read the LED states, it just "remembers" them in the `currentState` variable. Now the rest of the code becomes a straightforward implementation of the conditions you were given so...

> "if Left LED is on and Down is Pressed Change to Right LED"

```
    if (currentState == stateLeftLED) {
        if (Joystick == "D") {
            WriteLED ('R', LED_ON);
            WriteLED ('L', LED_OFF);
            currentState = stateRightLED;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

STM's HAL library offers a ReadPin function analog to the WritePin function you already used.

It's declaration looks as follows:

```
GPIO_PinState HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
```

Which means you could read the state of a certain pin like this:

```
GPIO_PinState ld6_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(LD6_GPIO_Port, LD6_Pin);
```

GPIO_PinState is an enumeration:

```
typedef enum
{
  GPIO_PIN_RESET = 0,
  GPIO_PIN_SET
}GPIO_PinState;
```

All that's left is comparing the return value of the read function (ld6_state) to either of the enumeration values. As mentioned by the first answer you'll most likely experience some bouncing of your inputs which is caused by the mechanical construction of your buttons. I guess figuring out how to solve that is part of the assignment so I'll leave that up to you. Keywords to look for: debounce or debouncing

Comment: Who mentioned STM? Are you assuming this based on the function calls in the OP?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know only STM libraries have functions with this very specific name and "HAL_" prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the state of an GPIO is saved in a register variable. You either need a definition of this variable or a vector pointing to its adress to read (or manipulate) it directly. Do you have documentation of the method WriteLED? It could give you a hint.

If you don't find anything you could still implement a flag to indicate which LED you switched on most recently.

Generally the Embedded Programming depends highly on the Chip you are working with and the corresponding compiler. 
So to give you a better answer, you should first provide important information like the Hardware and Software you are using and libraries you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to put a delay in your main loop.
Unless your joystick function locks the code until it sees a change, that toggle on your top LED is going to happen so fast that you are likely to see a dim glow or perhaps even nothing at all depending on the rise time of your hardware. 
Like Wizzard said you should be able to find the status of your LED by looking in a register. How this is done is totally down to your hardware. 
It would also most likely be suitable to use a few static booleans so you can save the state of the LEDs and check these to get your LED values, but this is not a perfect implementation. Register checks are better.